# How To Push Json Value From React.JS To .NET Abstract Class?

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, asp.net-web-api, abstract-class

I have no any idea how to push json value from react.js to .NET abstract class. Basically, here my abstract class

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(ConcreteOtherRegistry))]
[KnownType(typeof(ConcreteForeignerRetailRegistry))]
[KnownType(typeof(ConcreteUndetailedRegistry))]
[KnownType(typeof(ConcreteRetailRegistry))]
[KnownType(typeof(ConcretePublicRegistry))]
[KnownType(typeof(ConcreteCorporateRegistry))]

public abstract class ConcreteRegistryInfo
{
protected ConcreteRegistryInfo();

[DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
public long Oid { get; set; }
[DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
public short Status { get; set; }
[DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
public long LastUpdated { get; set; }
[DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
public long OperationRefNo { get; set; }
[DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
public string Address { get; set; }

public override string ToString();
}
```

and here is my web service

```
public class SaveApplicationParameters
    {
        public ConcreteRegistryInfo registryInfo{ get; set; }
    }

[HttpPost]
    public object[] SaveApplication([FromBody] SaveApplicationParameters saveApplicationParameters)
    {
        ConcreteApplication application = saveApplicationParameters.application;

        try
        {
            Com.BS.WaterSupplyAndSeverage.Services.WaterSupplyAndSewerage wssService = new Com.BS.WaterSupplyAndSeverage.Services.WaterSupplyAndSewerage();
            wssService.SaveApplication(application);
            object[] result = new object[1];
            result[0] = application.ApplicationNo;
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            FileLogger.Error(CLASS_NAME, "SaveApplication", e.Message, e.StackTrace, application, policy);
            BSCommunicationException commException = PrepareCommunicationException(e);
            throw new FaultException<BSCommunicationException>(commException, new FaultReason(commException.ExceptionMessage));
        }
    }
```

and here's my a sample code to push

```
 const body = { registryInfo: APPLICATION };
 axios.post('https://localhost:44396/api/SaveApplication', body)
  .then(async response => {
    SuccessOperation({ RESPONS_DATA: await response.data });
  })
  .catch(() => {
    FailedOperation({ RESPONSE_DATA: null })
  });
```

here is my jsonObject

```
let APPLICATION = {
      IdentityNumber:IdentityNumber,
      Name:Name,
      SurName:SurName,
      FatherName:FatherName,
      MotherName:MotherName,
      PlaceOfBirth:PlaceOfBirth,
      Gender:Gender,
      Email:Email,
      DateOfBirth:DateOfBirth,
      DayOfBirth:DayOfBirth,
      MonthOfBirth:MonthOfBirth,
      YearOfBirth:YearOfBirth,
      GsmNumber:GsmNumber,
      PhoneNumber:PhoneNumber,
      Retired:Retired,
      Address:Address,
      Oid:Oid
    }
```

In this example I'm sending ConcreteRetailRegistry Informations. But all classes(KnownType...) derive from ConcreteRegistryInfo, so firstly I have to push parameters to ConcreteRegistryInfo. Do you have any idea how I can do it?

Comment: Why does `ConcreteRegistryInfo` need to be abstract? Is your intent that the `registryInfo` property of the parameter passed to your service could be an instance of any of the classes derived from `ConcreteRegistryInfo`? And why does your JSON object only contain the `Address` and `Oid` properties out of the 5 `Required` properties in that class? I think I have an idea of what you should be doing but I want to be sure I understand the intent first.

Comment: Another question, are you using full .net framework or .net core? I'd assumed full .net framework as the question is tagged with `.net` rather than `.net-core`, but now I'm wondering whether that assumption is correct.

Comment: Hello @sbridewell I'm working on a big project. That project was created .net framework and ext.net2.0 before I took this project. Service side is really so huge. and many abstract classes were used in service side.   so I can't change this method. I'm changing client side from Ext.Net to React.JS , I have to figure out how to  push JSON value to abstract class. The answer of second question, this is a sample JSON of retail members. Which mean abstract class derive retail members for me. Do not over think about that json. If you know any solution just share it with me please. Thanks in advance

Comment: OK, so you're not changing the server-side code, you just want to rewrite the client in React.js, that's useful to know. Which part of this are you struggling with? Are you getting an error when trying to call the service? If so, is it an error in the browser or in the server-side code? Please share the details of the error in your question. If you're not getting an error, then what does happen when calling the server, and how does this differ from what you're expecting to happen?

Comment: Hello @sbridewell Yes I just want to re-write my client side in React.JS, I don't get any error, I'm sending and object which includes concreteRegisterInfo and other parameters. And when I check my parameters on service side which is coming from react.Js , I see my ConcreteRegisterInfo is null but other values are OK.

Comment: Now we've got a description of the expected and actual outcomes, it becomes clearer. If you change `const body = { registryInfo: APPLICATION };` in your client code to `const body = { ConcreteRegistryInfo: APPLICATION };` (this is case-sensitive) does it improve things?